# Laravel not taking MySQL login info

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to run `php artisan migrate` on my Laravel project but I keep getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied
 for user 'app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I created a python test program to connect to the database with the exact same info and it works, so I know the details are correct.

If you need it, info in .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=testapp
DB_USERNAME=app
DB_PASSWORD=123abc
```

Have I missed a step? Thanks in advance for your help! <3

Comment: check your credentials in config/database.php file

Comment: @LeenaPatel That takes from .env. In the error it shows that al the right info is going through, so it's not that.

Comment: try to  connect to db without password

Comment: @DejavuGuy No. The credentials are **NOT** the problem. I set up this account and it works with the python program.

Comment: are running php artisan serve? have you re-run the artisan serve?

Comment: Is MySQL setup to listen on a unix socket or 127.0.0.1? Perhaps try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @ryantxr MySQL is on MAMP. I'm also using valet. Also, if I give it localhost, it says access denied. If I give it 127.0.0.1, it says connection refused.

Comment: If I set it up for a socket, it can't find the mysql.sock file. Seems like it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the credentials, was the application serving before you updated the .env?

If it was you will need to run in the console:

`php artisan config:clear`

This will then re-read the .env file.

Comment: I've tried that, multiple times. Still doesn't work.